# How to use $_GET in wordpress pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Here's the thing...

I have created a button which on click opens a link like

```
 https://www.something.com/something/?term=something
```

or [at first, I thought this is a URL problem... so I tried some other] Like:-

```
 https://www.something.com/something.php?term=something
 https://www.something.com/something?term=something
```

and else

now on this link, I want to echo $_GET['term']... which not happening, there is no error in the console... how to be able to echo it

I know the answer is in this document but I don't know how to use this thing... can anyone please describe the right way step by step...
    https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: `echo $_GET['term']` will always work.

Comment: Is your intention to go through Wordpress routing or to directly access a php file in your server?

Answer (score 1):

get_query_arg : Retrieve **only public query variable** in the WP_Query class of the global $wp_query object.

I propose for security , use rewrite class in Wordpress :

```
/**
 * Add rewrite tags and rules
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
 */
/**
 * Add rewrite tags and rules
 */
function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%city%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^city/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?city=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);
```

for add to query arg :

```
/**
 * Register custom query vars
 *
 * @param array $vars The array of available query variables
 * 
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars
 */
function myplugin_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'city';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_register_query_vars' );
```

example link in site : **yoursite.com/city/45**

get data in wordpress :

```
$city = get_query_var( 'city' );
echo $city;
```

Comment: didnt worked.... i pasted the function in function.php and get_query_war in main page...plz help

Comment: you must flush rewrite after copy this code.go to setting -> permalink and click to save button.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite simple

```
echo get_query_var( 'term', 'default_value');
```

Obviously you have to add this in functions.php for custom variables

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ) {
  $vars[] = "my_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

read further details [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Comment: Dont forget you have to register custom query vars as mentioned by Mehrsahd in his answer

Comment: I have added the above code in the main page... and the second code in my theme's function.php but it is echoing "default_value".

Comment: @user10280601 replace my_var value with your query string variable and also value "term" in this line get_query_var( 'term', 'default_value');  with your query string variable. and default_value is optional parameter in this function to show something default if query string variable not found so you can set it what you want.

Comment: @AshfaqAhmed I have already done it but it still echoes "default value"

Comment: @KaiQing i have done what you told.... first code in function.php and second in the normal page but it is echoing "default value"